# How do I optimize the spawning of actors in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Currently, I'm using a blueprint script to generate and delete around 60 actors in a radius of a flying pawn.
This creates framerate spikes, and I've read that this is quite a heavy process.

So obviously I would like to increase the performance of this process by just placing the same logic in C++.
But I would like to know a couple of things first to make sure what I'm doing is right.

1 ) Is the `spawnActor` function in C++ by itself - faster - than the blueprint node?

2 ) Which kind of properties of the blueprint, increase the processing time of spawning? 
I know that for example enabling physics will increase the process time, but are there any more properties that I need to take into consideration?

I thank everyone taking their time reading this, and any kind of help is much appreciated :)

Comment: A blueprint exposed function is usually just calling the C++ directly, what's heftier is the overhead associated with blueprints execution compared to native C++. Do you have a lot of logic (e.g. complex algorithms in tick handlers) in blueprints?

Comment: [some interesting related read](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?3035-New-Twitch-livestream-with-Fortnite-developers-Thursday-April-17&p=19464&viewfull=1#post19464)

Comment: @MarcoA. I don't use ticks at all, everything is generated on a beginOverlap event. Checking out the link right now :)

Comment: @MarcoA. Alright, it might be the blueprint itself that is getting spawned into the scene. I do need to learn how to use the profiler of UE4.

Comment: yep, that seems a great use of your time to me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can't say that C++'s SpawnActor is faster, since the Blueprint's SpawnActor finally leads to the C++ SpawnActor. But of course if you directly write C++ codes then it saves the time of calling several functions routing Blueprint node to C++ function. Hence for the spike of SpawnActor I don't think it's because of calling Blueprint SpawnActor, i.e. calling C++ won't fix it.

The SpawnActor itself does have its cost, so calling it 60 times in a row surely makes a spike. I'm not very sure how many overhead is in SpawnActor, but at least I can guess that allocating memory for these new Actors cost some time. Also if your Actor template has a lot of components then it takes more time. So a common technique is to use an Actor Pool to pre-spawn some Actors and reuse them.

Comment: An actor pool huh, I will surely check it out, thanks :)

Comment: @Sem I bet you've already known Actor pool before I posted, I was just writing them for a completeness of my post :p

Answer (score 0):

C++ will be always faster than Blueprints because last are based on templates, so your compilation and bug fixing won't be easy.
Amount of characters will always affect performance because of CPU time, but it's ok. You must take into account that getting access to characters based on UE4 iterators and dedicated containers, so they are already optimised and thread safe.